# Ubuntu Dual boot feature for creating Windows-10 + Windows-11 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows

I recall that I have been able to easily build a dual boot Windows-Ubuntu system by:

1. Installing windows-10
2. Booting Ubuntu from USB and installing alongside existing windows.

The second step includes resizing the Windows partition and creating a new partition for Ubuntu.

If the goal is to be able to dual boot Windows-10 and Windows-11, is it possible to follow said procedure and somehow command Ubuntu to install Windows-11 from a .iso alongside the windows-10 install?  or Install Ubuntu and then somehow overwrite the Ubuntu with Windows-11?

I suspect this idea is not new, but have no idea what it is called to Google it.  Ideally there would be a procedure published on the internet?

Comment: Ubuntu provides many ISOs that use different installers, but the Ubuntu installers are intended to be used for installing the Ubuntu system they come with. I QA test systems & Ubuntu offers as boot options whatever OSes it can read (*file-systems in use, including if clean and not just type of fs impact results*) which can include most non-Ubuntu systems, but the dual boot procedure is usually controlled by whatever OS is last installed (*I usually let it install & fix it post-install; but we don't support Windows 11*). Dual boot means multiple OSes, not just two (*the dual boot here has 3*)

Comment: Have you tried [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/)? Did it not work or are you just trying to find an alternative method  of installing Windows after you've installed Ubuntu?

Comment: @karel Given an existing Windows 10 on a 2 TB NVME (20% full), the goal is to reside Windows 10 and create a new 500GB Partition for Windows 11.   Maybe the second partition can be carved out by Ubuntu?